# mongo template findAndModify return list

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I´m using mongotemplate.findAndModify, and I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve not just one document, but all of them that fit in with the filters that I put in my Criteria.
As I can see in the different method of this class We can put the object that has to cast the result, but in my case that I´m looking for a List I dont know how to make it.

Any idea somebody here?.

Reagards.

Comment: findAndModify updates a document atomically and returns it to the caller. since MongoDB has no atomicity across multiple documents it doesn't make sense to have findAndModify apply to more than one document - it wouldn't be atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I understood your question correctly. As per I know findAndModify modifies and returns just a single document, so no way it can return you a list of documents.